# Why I get "the requested layer 'background' is not part of the list" error if it is part of the list?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

The following code gives me the error:

```
! Package pgf Error: Sorry, the requested layer 'background' is not part of the
 layer list. Please verify that you provided \pgfsetlayers and that 'background
' is part of this list.
```

But `background` is in `\pgfsetlayers{background,main}`. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=center, 
    axis y line=center, 
    ticks=none
    ]
    \addplot[color=red,domain=-2:2,name path= mycurve]{x^2};
    \addplot[domain=-2:2,name path= myline]{x-1};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \addplot[red!10] fill between [of=myline and mycurve, soft clip={domain=-1:1}];
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess because `fill between` sets `set layers` which in turn uses another layer set in which no `background` layer exists. But why do you want to change the default layer where the `fill between` stuff is drawn into? And *if* this should be your goal you could also use the key--value `on layer =<layer name>` to do so.

Comment: @StefanPinnow thanks, is there a way to modify the `fill between` layers?

Comment: Sure, but this is quite some work. I guess it is much easier to use the "default" layers when `set layers` is set/active. Could you elaborate your final goal?

Comment: @StefanPinnow Just to have the filling behind the curves, to see the curve border, I know how to do it with some workaround, I'm wondering if there is a smart method.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Also the axis in foreground.

Comment: @StefanPinnow marmot already solved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I see meanwhile Stefan Pinnow already showed what the issue is. You need to use `set layers` or `axis on top` (or something of that sort) and then draw the filling on the desired layer, see section 4.27.2 of the pgfplots manual. The desired answer seem to be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis on top,
    axis x line=center, 
    axis y line=center, 
    ticks=none
    ]
    \addplot[color=red,domain=-2:2,name path= mycurve]{x^2};
    \addplot[domain=-2:2,name path= myline]{x-1};
    \addplot[red!10] fill between [of=myline and mycurve, soft clip={domain=-1:1}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, as [kindly pointed out by Stefan Pinnow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462426/why-i-get-the-requested-layer-background-is-not-part-of-the-list-error-if-it/462431?noredirect=1#comment1163060_462431), the `fill between` triggers automatically that the shaded area is on the `pre main` layer.

If you replace `axis on top` by `set layers`, you'll get

[image]

More options for layers are discussed in section 4.27.2 of the pgfplots manual. These additional options might be relevant if you want to draw several overlapping areas (and/or contours) in a certain order, and you cannot just order the various `\addplot`s to give the desired ordering.

Comment: `axis on top`!!!! Bad things happen not reading the manuals! (cit.)

Comment: @CarLaTeX The manual is neither in Italian nor marmot language, so it is really hard to read. (And I thought the quote was "Don't read the manual, bad things can happen." ;-)

Comment: To be a bit more precise: `set layers` is automatically set by pgfplots when there is a statement `\addplot fill between ...`, thus it must not be set explicitly. And also layer `pre main` is the default layer of `\addplot fill between`s which means the "fillings" are *always* behind all regular stuff drawn in the `axis` environment. Thus one will get the same result without stating this, too.

Comment: To sum up: You only need to add `axis on top` to get the desired result.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Yes, thanks! (The fact that `set layers` get invoked automatically when using `fill between` I did not know, yet `pre main` is really just an example to show what to do if you have several different things and want to put them on different layers.)

Comment: @CarLaTeX https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3973372#3973372

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Bottom-line: always trust the marmots. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to draw something on the background layer behind an axis:
with

```
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main} 
...
\begin{axis}[]
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
```

I got the error `Sorry, the requested layer 'background' is not part of the' is part of this list.`

After studying section [4.27.2 of the PGFPLOTS manual](https://markov.htwsaar.de/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#subsection.4.27.2), I found that PGFPLOTS creates its own default layers for axis environments: `axis background, axis grid, axis ticks, axis lines, axis tick labels, main, axis descriptions, axis foreground`.

Thus,

```
\begin{axis}[]
\begin{pgfonlayer}{axis background} % instead of background
```

did the trick for me.